# want to extract mobile numbers which is given in text without tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my code. How can I extract the mobile number from the data returned by the webpage?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.medindia.net/patients/doctor_search/dr-amiya-obstetrics-and-gynaecology-north-lakhimpur-assam-231775-1.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

data= soup.find('div',class_='col-xs-12')
h3 = data.find('h3')
print h3.text

p = data.find('p')

print p.text
r = data.find('span')

print r.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using findAll('p') instead of just find('p').

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.medindia.net/patients/doctor_search/dr-amiya-obstetrics-and-gynaecology-north-lakhimpur-assam-231775-1.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

data= soup.find('div',class_='col-xs-12')
h3 = data.find('h3')
print(h3.text)

p = data.findAll('p')

for pdata in p:
    print(pdata.text)

r = data.find('span')
print(r.text)
```

Output:

```
Dr. Amiya
ward no 12, k b road , north lakhimpur - 787001, assam

Phone : 91-3752-9435487Email : damircentre@gmail.com

damircentre@gmail.com
```

Comment: sometimes its running and another time its showing below error                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\medindia2.py", line 7, in <module>
    h3 = data.find('h3')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: That means data object is getting None value it in other words, it cannot find a div with class as 'col-xs-12'. In that case check if the request data returned but the URL really has this div with specified class or not. To avoid the error you can use try/catch block.

Comment: yes its working..i tried running the code for this site there are 806 pages for maharashtra state but it just giving me output for first 2 pages nor showing any error